# How to load only specific information wit PyQt4

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

To make my question clear I will give an example:
let's say I go to the http://python.org and I want to load content that is inside `<div id="content'> .... </div>`. And not the rest, don't want to load any search bars, footer, side bars and so on. The idea is to save bandwidth.

My guess is to use `SIGNAL - loadStarted()` but I'm kind of confused in how to write an appropriate `SLOT`.

Any comments, suggestions are very welcome.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be really specific to PyQt. Unless you are asking how to download the page content first, parse out only what you want, and THEN render it?

Comment: Not exactly, I can achieve what you saying pretty easy, but it will still download the whole page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can do that... When you load the url http://python.org it will download and parse, render, etc the entire page you can't load specific parts of that page.

Edit: also loadStarted() refers to the entire page, not parts of it